# Mysql - Get number of minutes in each hour when beginning and ending time are in different hours

Tags: mysql

I have an application that records login and logout datetimestamps into a mysql database. Each user login and logout is a row. I need to create a report that will show by user and by hour the number of minutes each user was logged in. I can figure out how to do it by using TIMESTAMPDIFF between the two timestamps and then grouping by hour on one of the timestamps. But I don't know how to do it when the login may be at 11:53 and logout may be at 13:06. Where it should show 7 minutes for the 11th hour, 60 for 12th, and 6 for 13th. Instead, the way I am doing it now would show 73 minutes for the 11th hour (if I group by login time).

Comment: This type of thing is difficult in SQL, it would probably be much easier to do in the client application language.

Comment: It gets even more complicated if the login and logout can cross midnight boundaries, so login is at `23:50` and logout is `01:15`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easiest to do this if you create another table that just has all the hours you might need to report over as timestamps.  Say this table is hourlist and the timestamp column in it is hour

Then you want a query like this:

```
select hour, userid,
   case
       when login < hour and logout >= ADDTIME(hour,'1:00:00.0') then '1:00:00.0'
       when login >= hour and logout < ADDTIME(hour, '1:00:00.0')then TIMEDIFF(logout, login)
       when login >= hour and logout > ADDTIME(hour, '1:00:00.0') then TIMEDIFF(ADDTIME(hour, '1:00:00.0'), login)
       when login < hour and logout < ADDTIME(hour, '1:00:00.0') then TIMEDIFF(logout, hour)
       else '00:00:00.0'
   end case
from hourlist join loginlogout
on (login >= hour and login < ADDTIME(hour,'1:00:00.0')) or (logout >= hour
   and logout < ADDTIME(hour,ADDTIME(hour,'1:00:00.0'))
order by hour
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! This is close to working. However, I need to get a total of the minutes and it doesn't seem to aggregate. When I add a group by, I just get the first login result for the hour instead of it aggregating all login minutes for that user within that hour. Any ideas for me?

Comment: What do you mean by aggregate?  This query should give you hour, user, and minutes for that user in that hour (expressed as a timediff)-- you shouldn't need an additional group by

Comment: Oops, I did group by instead of the order by above. Thanks!